# Get file mouseover text

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to get the filename or mouseover text of a file that is under the cursor in Python? For example, the cursor in the image below is over the file 'twelve'. Is there any way to get the text 'twelve' or the mouseover text of that file? Thanks.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

def onKeyPress(event):
    text.config(text='You pressed %s\n' % (event.char, ))

root = tk.Tk()

w = 600
h = 200
x = 50
y = 100
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))


frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

text = tk.Label(frame)
text.place(x=400, y=120)

root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this a program you wrote? It's not clear if you're asking about your program, or trying to get the text from another program. Can you create a [mcve] that displays the list of files?

Comment: Essentially, its a program I'm writing using tkinter. All I want to do right now is just have the filename text appear as a label in the GUI when I hover over it. Right now all it does is show which keyboard button was clicked as a label. So similar to how the value of the text label changes based on the keyboard, I'd like another label that changes based on which file is being hover over.

Comment: `<Enter>`/`<Leave>` means `start hover/end hover`

Comment: I've done something like this in the past though I can't find my code - maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524072/creating-a-mouse-over-text-box-in-tkinter

Comment: Are you trying to show file name under the mouse pointer from *windows explorer*?